# Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.million.model.Domain` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: spring, list, csv, kotlin, jackson

I'm using Kotlin, Spring Boot, Jackson dataformat csv. Not sure, how I can return response from my csv as List of domain objects. and I have the following error
Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.million.model.Domain` out of START_ARRAY token

My code is the following:

```
@Service
class DomainService {
    fun getDomains(): List<Domain> {


        val mapper = CsvMapper()
        mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY)
        val csvFile = File("myCsv.csv")
        val response: List<Domain> = mapper.readerFor(Domain::class.java).readValues<Domain>(csvFile).readAll()
        return response
    }
}

data class Domains(var domain: String){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting this line, as otherwise you are wrapping each csv line in an array, which leads to your error message.

```
mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY)
```

Your code otherwise looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this and trying to fix the next error: Kotlin Jackson no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('GlobalRank') it's one of the row in my csv file

Comment: This looks better , though. You need to add more code/description to your problem. Add a full csv row including column headers + any jackson annotations you might have put on your domain class.